# how to tell protractor NOT to wait till the page is loaded completly

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, saucelabs, gulp-protractor

i'm testing a non angular page with protractor on sauce labs. 
my tests are failing often because of the logout page. 
there are ad's on the logout page and however how long i try to set the timeout,
it's reaching it and the spec fail.

I'm getting the same failures a) & b) during the tests when i'm sure i'm not reaching the timeout.
Any ideas?

my timeouts:

```
allScriptsTimeout: 100000,
defaultTimeoutInterval: 110000,
getPageTimeout: 120000,
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
```

Error messages:

```
a) ✗ logout
- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

b)
✗ logout
- Failed: Wait timed out after 60096ms
```

Code:

```js
    beforeEach(() => {
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
    beforeEach(function(done) { done(); }, 10000);
    });
  
    ListPage.logout.click();
    browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(ListPage.logout), 120000);
```

Answer (score 1):

(Answer to the question if i got ignoreSynchronization=true) i got this in my config.the specs run successful locally(most the time), i have tried a lot things, different timeouts, beforeEach(function(done) { done(); }, 10000);. expected conditions for every click but the tests are still failing. And the worst thing is when the logout fails the next spec is also failing, like shown below.

```
[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31] A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31]     ✗ logout
[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31]       - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31] **************************************************
[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31] *                    Failures                    *
[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31] **************************************************
[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31] 
[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31] 1) Feedback Test open feedback
[iphone 9.2 OS X 10.10 #31]   - Failed: Element does not exist in cache
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to put this in your config file for non-angular apps which would solve the issue:

```
    onPrepare: function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do, but in any case you should be aware that the `beforeEach` is called before each spec, i.e. before each `it`function.

I work with Protractor in an web app continously polling a timeout, forcing me to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` My advice is: if you can avoid to do so... Just avoid it. You would spent at least half of your time debugging synchronization issues.

EDIT: **Since you are testing a non-angular app, you have to use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`**

This means you will have to manage synchronization yourself, and ensure every command sent to the browser will be sent when you need to.

In this case, manage the synchronization yourself by writing something like

```
ListPage.logout.click()
.then(function(){
    browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(ListPage.logout), 120000);
});
```

Comment: when i change form browser.ignoreSynchronization =true; to false the specs fails with "no angular found on page" ?!

Comment: OK, sorry I didn't see your app is a non-angular Web App. It is just normal, then. I will edit my post accordingly.